# Program won't start unless debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a program I made using Visual Studio that won't start unless VS is debugging.  Where should I look for problems?

The program works when debugging through VS but won't start from the debug folder. The program works fine when debugging. No output is given.

Comment: well you should look at the console output and a better description than "won't start" would be helpful.

Comment: He did say 'No output is given' to be fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of startup problem I'd suggest running your app in Windbg (part of the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009)).  Do File -> Attach to executable and then hit F5.  You should get more informative output there.  I suspect it's a dll dependency or manifest problem.  Another useful tool is the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) which may highlight some dlls that are on Visual Studio's path but not your default path, which may also explain the error.  Another thing to try is check that all types of debug output are being shown in Visual Studio: right-click to get the context menu in the debug output window and ensure it's showing exception messages and module load messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on Stop on Exceptions

Debug - Exceptions - Common Language Runtime Exceptions (thrown and user unhandled)